# Spark streaming 24X7 with updateStateByKey Issue

Tags: spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming for 24/7 and using updateStateByKey 
Is is possible to run spark streaming 24/7?
If Yes wont the updateStateByKey grow big, how to handle it?
Do we have to reset/delete updateStateByKey periodically when we run 24/7 if not how and when to reset it?
Or Spark handles in a distributed way? how to increate the memory/storage dynamically.

I get these following errors when the updateStateByKey Grows

```
Array out of bound exception

Exception while deleting local spark dir: /var/folders/3j/9hjkw0890sx_qg9yvzlvg64cf5626b/T/spark-local-20141026101251-cfb4
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: /var/folders/3j/9hjkw0890sx_qg9yvzlvg64cf5626b/T/spark-local-20141026101251-cfb4
```

How to handle this.. Please point me if there are any docs? i am completely stuck, any help is much appreciated.. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Optional.absent() in Java and None in Scala to remove keys. Working example can be found at http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/how-to-do-near-real-time-sessionization-with-spark-streaming-and-apache-hadoop/.

Comment: Thanks a lot i shall try

Answer (score 0):

Update the key with None will delete it from spark. If you want to keep the key for a certain amount of time, you can attach an expire time to the key, and check it every batch.

For example, here's the code to count records by minute:

```
val counts = lines.map(line => (currentMinute, 1))
val countsWithState = counts updateStateByKey { (values: Seq[Int], state: Option[Int]) =>
  if (values.isEmpty) { // every key will be iterated, even if there's no record in this batch
    println("values is empty")
    None // this will remove the key from spark
  } else {
    println("values size " + values.size)
    Some(state.sum + values.sum)
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please share how to set none.. Say for example if i applying groupby for every 1 hr, now its 2 hr , by 3rd hr 2 hr data will not change how to set none for 2hr key and save it to external file for future use? any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Function2<List<Double>, Optional<Double>, Optional<Double>> updateFunction =new Function2<List<Double>, Optional<Double>, Optional<Double>>() { @Override public Optional<Double> call(List<Double> values, Optional<Double> state) {
         Double newSum = state.or(0D); 
              if(values.isEmpty()){
               System.out.println("empty value");
               return ScalaLang.none();
              }else{
               for (double i : values) {
                  newSum += i;
               return Optional.of(newSum);
              }}};
            
       not working,plz advice

Comment: i return option<double> when i try setting scalaLang.none() it shows error

Answer (score 0):

pyspark : updateStateByKey(self, updateFunc, numPartitions=None, initialRDD=None)

*Return a new "state" DStream where the state for each key is updated by applying
the given function on the previous state of the key and the new values of the key.*

*@param updateFunc: State update function. If this function returns None, then
                           corresponding state key-value pair will be eliminated.*

updateFunc method return None, state key-value pair remove;